# How to fix: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1?

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import re
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter
nltk.download('stopwords')
stemmer = nltk.SnowballStemmer('english')

data = pd.read_csv('BA_reviews.csv',index_col='Unnamed: 0')
print(data.info())
print(data.head())


stopword=set(stopwords.words('english'))
def clean(text):
  text = str(text).lower()
  text = re.sub('\[.*?\]', '', text)
  text = re.sub('https?://\S+|www\.\S+', '', text)
  text = re.sub('<.*?>+', '', text)
  text = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', text)
  text = re.sub('\n', '', text)
  text = re.sub('\w*\d\w*', '', text)
  text = [word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in stopword]
  text=" ".join(text)
  text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split(' ')]
  text=" ".join(text)
  text = re.sub('✅ Trip Verified |', '', text)
  text = re.sub('✅', '', text)
  text = re.sub('Trip Verified', '', text)
  text = re.sub('Verified', '', text)
  text = re.sub(' trip verifi', '', text)
  return text
data['reviews'] = data['reviews'].apply(clean)

print(data.head())
print(data.shape)


freq_words = pd.Series(" ".join(data).lower().split()).value_counts()[:50]
print(freq_words)

#To plot the frequent words
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
freq_words.plot.barh(x=freq_words[0], y=freq_words[1])
plt.show()
```

The CSV-file had two columns (`unnamed` and `reviews`) and I tried to pop just one column, but it wasn't working, even when tried to drop the one I needed using `drop()`, so I had to settle for using `Index_col`. Am I on the right path?

And I am trying to plot a bar chart of the most frequent words from a review, but it is throwing an

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the full traceback. And please provide a [mre].

Comment: `freq_words` is a series, so `freq_words[0]` is just one item (same for `[1]`)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the following line:

```
freq_words.plot.barh(x=freq_words[0], y=freq_words[1])
```

The `barh` function from `matplotlib` takes as parameters the name of the columns in the dataframe, not actual data. Since `freq_words` is a `pandas.Series`, it only has one dimension, hence you're trying to access a second dimension that does not exist, which is why it's throwing an `IndexError`.

In your case, the indices of the `Series` represent the words and the values represent the count of those words. When plotting a horizontal bar plot (`barh`), you do not need to specify `x` and `y` as this is already determined by the `Series` itself.

To plot the frequent words, you can simply do:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
freq_words.plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

This should resolve the `IndexError` that you're experiencing.

As for the CSV file, if you're having trouble with unnamed columns, it might be because your CSV file has an index column that pandas is reading in as a regular column. If this is the case, then using `index_col='Unnamed: 0'` is a correct approach. It tells pandas to use that column as the index of the DataFrame.

Comment: It didnt work...instead it gave me a bar for the whole reviews not distribution of the frequent words

Comment: Did ChatGPT create this output, or was it another AI?